# save the output of each for loop iteration to split a nested list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tuples, iteration

I have a list of lists that looks like this `mylst`

```
[[('Salmon', 9), ('Fish&Chips', 3), ('Pasta', 8), ('Shrimp', 10)],
 [('Shrimp', 8), ('Fish&Chips', 10), ('Salmon', 9), ('Pasta', 7)],
 [('Shrimp', 10), ('Fish&Chips', 6), ('Salmon', 8), ('Pasta', 5)],
 [('Shrimp', 7), ('Pasta', 9), ('Salmon', 8), ('Fish&Chips', 8)],
 [('Fish&Chips', 10), ('Shrimp', 8), ('Salmon', 9), ('Pasta', 3)]]
```

I can access the sublists if I print the desired index

`mylst[0]`

which returns

```
[('Salmon', 9), ('Fish&Chips', 3), ('Pasta', 8), ('Shrimp', 10)]
```

But I would like to store each sublist in a new list.

*Because eventually I would like to extract the items(tuple index 0) and the quantity ordered (tuple index 1) for each sublist and store them in two separate lists. But I can't do this if I can't split the lists*

I tried to iterate through the main list

```
newlst=[]

for sublst in mylst:
    newlst.append(sublst)
```

and

```
newlst=[]

for i in range(len(mylst)):
    for sublst in mylst:
        newlst.append(mylst[i])
```

I am not sure how to split then store multiple outputs from each iteration of the for loop.

The desired output is to have the 5 sublists as seperate lists. For example

```
lst1=[('Salmon', 9), ('Fish&Chips', 3), ('Pasta', 8), ('Shrimp', 10)]

lst2 = [('Shrimp', 8), ('Fish&Chips', 10), ('Salmon', 9), ('Pasta', 7)]
```

and so on.

note: my question is not duplicate of this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables), as I have read the solutions. I want to store my sublists in seperate lists. which is different.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: 5 lists. Each one contains  the values of one of the sublist.

Comment: You mean something like `a,b,c,d,e = mylst` (which is quite inefficient way of dealing multiple lists btw)

Comment: What happens if you have more than five lists?

Comment: I am looking for  a general solution.  A for loop that can iterate through the main list according the number of sublists the main list contains.

Comment: Why do you need *lst1*, *lst2*, ..., when you already have `mylst[0]`, `mylst[1]`, ...? That's bad design. What would happen if *mylst* contained 1000 sublists? Having *lst1* ... *lst1000* would **make absolutely no sense**.

Comment: As others have said, I think OP should re-evaluate whether what's being asked for makes any sense. Essentially, you want 5 variables identified by letters. But that's the whole point of a list--a collection of 5 variables identified by numbers. It's much more convenient that way. If you really need letters, use a dict, but creating separate variables makes it harder to work with, not easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to unpack the list then you can do what Chris said above and just do `a,b,c,d,e = mylst`, but if what you want is to repackage the data in a more usable way, then I suggest storing this in a pandas dataframe. You can do that with the following code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

my_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(mylst).reshape(-1, 2),
    columns=['item', 'quantity'])
```

Comment: the main list I provided is extracted from a dataframe. Each sublist is a row of one column in the dataframe. I would like to save each row from the specified column to seperate list.

Comment: Like the comments above say, you might want to re-evaluate your strategy here. You can unpack the list `lst1, lst2, lst3 ... = mylst` but that is a bad design pattern. Pandas dataframes are built for handling this sort of data, and it's likely you can use that framework to solve your problem much more efficiently

Comment: Thank you Kyle. I will try to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can make one massive nested list by using a `for` loop each containing the desired list.

```
for each in lst:
seplist = [] #splitted list of each digit of every integer
for eachagain in str(each):
    seplist.append(integer)
nestedlist.append(seplist)
```

Here the nested list can be separated and stored by using another `for` loop